# Updatepanel issue, client side event not firing

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

I have an `<UpdatePanel>` within which I have a *LinkButton*, and I am trying to handle its client side click event before its partial postback event occurs. I am using jquery for this, and its click event is not firing at all.
The code works fine without *updatepanel*, but fails with it.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ContinueTestPanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <div id="Pause-Screen">
        <asp:Label ID="ServerMessage" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div class="submit">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="ContinueTest" runat="server" text="Continue" CssClass="continue-test"/>
    </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Corresponding jquery code :

```
$(".continue-test").click(function() {
    $(".pause-screen-wrapper").hide();
});
```

I have double tested, but of no use.
Your thoughts plz.

Comment: There's no Click event at all on your LinkButton so I don't see what partial postback it would perform.

Comment: There's not intended to be a postback.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it could be a conflict with the Microsoft AJAX library and jQuery.  Have you tried using `$.noConflict();` ?

Comment: Yes i have used noconflict(), and then tried but to no use at all.
I have used $addHandler(element, 'click', this.myClickHandler); after reading this link http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/tutorials/CustomClientEvents/default.aspx 
but this also doesnt help. I have double checked everything.